# Reference API Gateway in Serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am using the following serverless.yaml configuration, with the `serverless-iam-roles-per-function` plugin.

```
service: tester
frameworkVersion: "3"

plugins:
  - serverless-iam-roles-per-function

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  stage: dev
  region: eu-west-3
  httpApi:
    cors: true

custom:
  APIGatewayConnection: "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-3:ACCOUNTID:*/@connections/*"

functions:
  Checker:
    handler: lambda/checker.handler
    iamRoleStatementsName: Checker-Role
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - execute-api:ManageConnections
        Resource:
          - ${self:custom.APIGatewayConnection}
    events:
      - httpApi:
          method: GET
          path: /check
```

Instead of writing the ARN of the API Gateway in the custom variables, how can I reference it in the iamRoleStatements dynamically?

Answer (score 3):

To understand what can be returned by [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html) references, we need to inspect the CloudFormation resource you are using.

In your case, when using `httpApi`, it generates `AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api`, and it returns only two things:

- ApiEndpoint
- ApiId

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-api.html#aws-resource-apigatewayv2-api-return-values

Regardless of the resource name auto-generated by Serverless Framework, you must build the ARN manually. The ARN pattern is:

```
arn:[partition]:execute-api:[region]:[account-id]:[api-id]/[stage]/[route-key]

arn:aws:execute-api:[region]:[account-id]:[api-id]/[stage]/[METHOD_HTTP_VERB]/[Resource-path]
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/arn-format-reference.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-invoke-api.html

You can check the name convention list of Serverless Framework in this page:

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources

Because we need to reference CloudFormation resources generated by Serverless Framework, we need to use CloudFormation intrinsic function to transform the ARN above into:

```
custom:
  APIGatewayConnection: !Sub arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${HttpApi}/${HttpApiStage}/@connections/*
```

And going back to your question. There's no dynamic way to reference this resource ARN. You need to build the ARN manually.

Comment: Thank you! That actually solves it for me. It is still somewhat dynamic in a way where I should not input manually the api-id. This will also be helpful to pass it to my lambda functions.